# Html attribute 'Max' with float value make problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to show a popup on submit if the value is less than the max attribute. I am able to achieve that with the HTML5 attribute like this: `<input type='number' max='21' />`
but the problem is that when the max value is a float number like `<input type='number' max='21.1' />` then it shows another popup saying that the value must be less than 21.

I've searched and I can solve that problem with Javascript but I want to use the max attribute even when the value is a float number.

`<input type='number' max='21.1' />`
`<button type='submit'>Submit</button>`

I want the form to be able to submit even if the value is 21 or 21.1 unless it is 21.2 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `step` property like this:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" max="21.1" step="0.1"/>
</form>
```

Alternatively you can use `any` as value:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" max="21.1" step="any"/>
</form>
```